# Session only captures the data of the last object within the list

Tags: c#, json, api, session-state

Session["DeviceIDs"] has a list stored with two ids. The Foreach method will pass each id to the web url/deviceIDs. The only id that's getting read is the last id. How can I pass all of the id's stored in Session["DeviceIDs]? Could this have something to do with var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);?? Thanks in advance

```
    public async void PatchMethodAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (Session["DeviceIDs"] != null)
            {
                //Check all ids in Session
                foreach (var ids in Session["DeviceIDs"].ToString())
                {
                    //Pass each individual id from Session to device id in url
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "https://www.website.com/devices/" + Session["DeviceIDs"]))
                    {
                        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"enabled\": \"y\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this

```
List<Task<ResponseObject>> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var id in Session["DeviceIDs"].ToString())
{
    ...//create the request Message using id
    tasks.Add(httpClient.SendAsync(request));
}

var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```